# React Router incompatible with specific react components

Tags: javascript, react-router

I'm currently developing a website and everything was alright until I started developing separate mob vers for the desktop pnes, and after some period of time, I noticed that most of the urls are not rendering! And I tried removing all nested routes, moving them all to App.js where the switch and browser router are, and still can access only a few pages! And even most of the desktop components aren't rendering, replacing `<Route path="/pathname"><Components/></Route>` syntax with `<Route path='/pathname" component={<>Component</>}/>` didn't help.

I attached a piece of the unrendering component. And also my App.js. Everyhting was working fine before that even when first mob components were injected!I wonder if someone has any similar problems...

```html
<Route path="/signup"><><Global>
          { device === "mobile" ? <SignUpMob/> : <SignUp/> }
          </Global></></Route>
          <Route path="/loggedin"><><Global>
          { device === "mobile" ? <AfterSignInMob/> : <AfterSignIn/> }</Global></></Route>
           <Route path="/signedup"><><Global>
           { device === "mobile" ? <AfterSignUpMob/> : <AfterSignUp/> }</Global></></Route>
           <Route path="/admin"><><Global>
             { device === "mobile" ? "Mobile version - not developed yet!" : <Admin/> }
             </Global></></Route>
          <Route path="/meme"><><Global>
             { device === "mobile" ? <MemeMob/> : <Meme/> }
             </Global></></Route>
           <Route path="/factsnstats-media"><><Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? <MediaMob/> : <Media/> }
            </Global></></Route>
          <Route path="/factsnstats-election"><><Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? <ElectionMob/> : <Election/> }
            </Global></></Route>
          <Route path="/factsnstats-sharefacts"><><Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? <ShareYourFactsMob/> : <ShareFacts/> }
            </Global></></Route>
          <Route path="/factsnstats-datanstats">
          <> <Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? <DatanStatsMob/> : <DatanStats/> }
            </Global></>
            </Route>
          <Route path="/specificpost"><><Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? <SpecificPostMob/> : <SpecificPost/> }
            </Global></></Route>
          <Route path="/signin"><><Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? <SignInMob/> : <SignIn/> }
            </Global></></Route>
           <Route path="/politics-our" ><><Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? "Mobile version - not developed yet!" : <Our/> }
            </Global></></Route>
          <Route path="/politics-we"><><Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? "Mobile version - not developed yet!" : <We/> }
            </Global></></Route>
          <Route path="/comments"><><Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? <SpecificPostExtendedMob/>: <SpecificPostExtended/> }
            </Global></></Route>
          <Route path="/mzs-popular"><> <Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? "Mobile version - not developed yet!" : <MZsPopular/> }
            </Global></></Route>
           <Route path="/mzs-general"><><Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? "Mobile version - not developed yet!" : <MZsGeneral/> }
            </Global></></Route>
          <Route path="/writepost"><><Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? "Mobile version - not developed yet!" : <WritePost/> }
            </Global></></Route>
          <Route path="/" exact><> <Global>
            { device === "mobile" ? <BeforeSignInMob/> : <SignIn/> }
            </Global></></Route>
```

```html
export default function PoliticsWe() {
  return (
    <>
     <Header><HeaderImg src="../../assets/headerpic.png"/><Navbar><span>mypage</span>| <span>log out</span></Navbar></Header>
      <Content><SideBar/><RightFrame><Title>Politics<Subtitle>We Forum</Subtitle></Title>
      <Tables>
        <Table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr><td><div></div></td><td>Politics Our Forum 1 All time likes post. Politics Our Forum 1 All time likes post. Politics Our Forum 1 All time likes post. Politics Our Forum 1 All time likes post. Politics Our Forum 1 All time likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div></div></td><td>Politics Our Forum 2 All time likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div></div></td><td>Politics Our Forum 3 All time likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div></div></td><td>Politics Our Forum 4 All time likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div></div></td><td>Politics Our Forum 5 All time likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </Table>
        <RightTable>
<thead><tr><th>Title</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ID</td><td>MZs Recent 3 days likes post</td><td><div><span><img src="../../assets/likes.png" alt=""/>3526</span><span><img src="../../assets/comments.png" alt=""/>3526</span></div></td></tr>
  </tbody></RightTable>
        </Tables>
      </RightFrame></Content>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: You can remove all the routes and then start by placing 1 by 1 routes which will help you to find the issue with smaller setup.

Comment: Hi, Rajdeep, a great idea, I'll try that out now! Thank you so much!

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" to my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) (hint: never)